# How can I send an Arraylist of HashMaps to _POST? And then how can I dissect the array in PHP?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I’m writing an Android app which collects user information and ultimately stores that in mySQL.
To add a new user, I’m sending _POST data to a PHP script from Android using:

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
       .appendQueryParameter("id",params.get("id"))
       .appendQueryParameter("name",params.get("name"))
       .appendQueryParameter("email",params.get("email"));

String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
```

On the PHP side, I’m receiving the _POST data and inserting to mySQL using:

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$query = "INSERT INTO users(id,name,email) VALUES('$id','$name','$email')";
```

Simple stuff.  However, I would also like to bulk add thousands of such records in one shot.

No problem on the Java side: I have an

```
Arraylist<HashMap<String,String>>
```

to hold these thousands of ‘rows’ of user data.

However, how can I pass this Arraylist of HashMaps to _POST? 
In turn,  on the PHP side, how can I dissect the lengthy _POST data (I would imagine breaking down an array) and write to the mySQL database?

I’ve not found a specific example of this on SO, on the Java end or the PHP end.

Thanks to the power of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use an interchangeable format for that, `JSON` for example.

Convert a Java hashmap to a JSON object through: [`new JSONObject(map);`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Then you could decode it in PHP, either manually or through an existing function, e.g. [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: This makes sense.  Now I just have to figure out how to extract a nested JSON array in PHP.